# Finding a column count by day/month

Tags: sql

How do I find the sum of a column eg. 'PlanTotal' by either day or month of another column eg. 'PlanStartDate' within the last six months?

I've got as far as this but don't know how to separate the sum into days or month.

```
SELECT SUM(PlanTotal) as PlanTotal
FROM TEST.dbo.Plans
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, cast(cast(PlanStartDate as varchar(8)) as datetime), GETDATE()) <= 6
```

Thanks

.....

I've used

```
SELECT SUM(PlanTotal) as PlanTotal,PlanStartDate
FROM TEST.dbo.Plans
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MONTH, cast(cast(PlanStartDate as varchar(8)) as datetime), GETDATE()) <= 6
GROUP BY PlanStartDate
ORDER BY PlanStartDate
```

This brings up the Plan Total and PlanStartDate by individual day but I still can't seem to work out grouping each month.

If I do this:

```
SELECT SUM(PlanTotal) as PlanTotal,MONTH(PlanStartDate)
FROM TEST.dbo.Plans
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MONTH, cast(cast(PlanStartDate as varchar(8)) as datetime), GETDATE()) <= 6
GROUP BY MONTH(PlanStartDate)
ORDER BY PlanStartDate
```

Using the month group by, it just throws an error;

```
Column "TEST.dbo.Plans.PlanStartDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: what do you mean, "day or month"? You want to find the number days between two dates? Plus, what is the point of the double cast? If planstartdate is a date/datetimevalue already, you're just waisting the DB's time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need to do a count of the Plan Total for each day, similarly a Plan Total count for each month, using the last six months of data.  I had to change the value to datetime as the value was numeric to begin with.

Comment: so `group by month(planstartdate), day(planstartdate)`. you don't need to cast anything.

Answer (score 1):

The following should help, however it wont display any records for dates which are non-existent in the `PlanStartDate` column

```
SELECT SUM(PlanTotal) as PlanTotal
       ,PlanStartDate
FROM TEST.dbo.Plans
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, cast(cast(PlanStartDate as varchar(8)) as datetime), GETDATE())<= 6
Group By PlanStartDate
```